# azure functions on Node js return error mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.users. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred

Tags: node.js, sql-server, azure-functions, tedious, mscorlib

I am using azure core tools with nodejs v14, the project works fine on every other device. But for some reason in my workstation it returns the following:

```
mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.users. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. C:<project_root_folder>\node_modules\@tediousjs\connection-string\lib\parser\sql-connection-string.js:259
```

I am using mssql library to connect to my sql server.

The remaining error is as follows:

```html
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token ...
    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)
    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (<project_root_folder>\node_modules\@tediousjs\connection-string\lib\index.js:6:33).
[10/26/2021 2:05:21 PM] {"id":"b7dd0606-587a-4c3c-82ae-a8e289a5a72d","requestId":"37ab81c6-2a96-4ae2-8e25-8ecbe14c5f6a","statusCode":500,"errorCode":0,"message":"Exception while executing function: Functions.users -> One or more errors occurred. -> <project_root_folder>\\node_modules\\@tediousjs\\connection-string\\lib\\parser\\sql-connection-string.js:259\n                    ...item,\n      
              ^^^\n\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token ...\n    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)\n    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)\n    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (<project_root_folder>\\node_modules\\@tediousjs\\connection-string\\lib\\index.js:6:33)","errorDetails":"Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.FunctionInvocationException : Exception while executing function: Functions.users ---> System.AggregateException : One or more errors occurred. ---> <project_root_folder>\\node_modules\\@tediousjs\\connection-string\\lib\\parser\\sql-connection-string.js:259\n                    ...item,\n                    ^^^\n\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token ...\n    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)\n    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)\n
   at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)\n    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (<project_root_folder>\\node_modules\\@tediousjs\\connection-string\\lib\\index.js:6:33)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)\r\n   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at EdgeJs.Edge.Func(String code)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.CreateFunctionTarget(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionLoader`1.GetFunctionTargetAsync[T](Int32 attemptCount)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.GetFunctionTargetAsync()\r\n  
 at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.NodeFunctionInvoker.InvokeCore(Object[] parameters,FunctionInvocationContext context)\r\n   at
async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Description.FunctionInvokerBase.Invoke(Object[] parameters)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.VoidTaskMethodInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnType](TReflected instance,Object[] arguments)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionInvoker`2.InvokeAsync[TReflected,TReturnValue](Object instance,Object[] arguments)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.InvokeAsync(IFunctionInvoker invoker,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,CancellationTokenSource timeoutTokenSource,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource,Boolean throwOnTimeout,TimeSpan timerInterval,IFunctionInstance instance)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithWatchersAsync(IFunctionInstance instance,ParameterHelper parameterHelper,TraceWriter traceWriter,CancellationTokenSource functionCancellationTokenSource)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception : <project_root_folder>\\node_modules\\@tediousjs\\connection-string\\lib\\parser\\sql-connection-string.js:259\n                    ...item,\n                    ^^^\n\nSyntaxError: Unexpected token ...\n    at createScript (vm.js:56:10)\n  
 at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:97:10)\n    at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)\n    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)\n    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)\n    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)\n    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)\n    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)\n    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)\n    at Object.<anonymous> (<project_root_folder>\\node_modules\\@tediousjs\\connection-string\\lib\\index.js:6:33)<---\r\n \r\n   End of inner exception\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.ExecuteWithLoggingAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.FunctionExecutor.TryExecuteAsync(IFunctionInstance functionInstance,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Executors.ExceptionDispatchInfoDelayedException.Throw()\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.JobHost.CallAsync(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.ScriptHost.CallAsync(String method,Dictionary`2 arguments,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.WebScriptHostManager.HandleRequestAsync(FunctionDescriptor function,HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.Host.FunctionRequestInvoker.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken,WebScriptHostManager scriptHostManager,WebHookReceiverManager webHookReceiverManager)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<ExecuteAsync>b__0(??)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http.HttpRequestManager.ProcessRequestAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,Func`3 processRequestHandler,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Controllers.FunctionsController.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken
cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.Cors.CorsMessageHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.WebScriptHostHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Script.WebHost.Handlers.SystemTraceHandler.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at async System.Web.Http.HttpServer.SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request,CancellationToken cancellationToken)"}
[10/26/2021 2:05:21 PM] mscorlib: Exception while executing function: Functions.users. mscorlib: One or more errors occurred. <project_root_folder>\node_modules\@tediousjs\connection-string\lib\parser\sql-connection-string.js:259
                    ...item,
                    ^^^
```

Please, if anyone knows what's up.. let me know..

Comment: error msg is clear: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token"

Comment: that's the thing, the same ... is running smoothly on other devices without error. And even i I comment out the ... also it is an javascript spread syntax used to hand array objects. :(

Comment: possibly a driver version difference/?

Comment: both system have the same npm and node versions. Is that what you mean by driver?

Comment: It might be with some `encoding` issue in the app.js file. try creating app.js file newly and replace it with your old one and try running it.

Comment: @HariKrishnaRajoli-MT I am fairly new to nodejs typescript. can you please guide me where the app.js file might be?